# How to avoid this column so that I only get a remaining data in csv and not the Unamed: 0 column when I save the dataframe as new csv file

Tags: python

I have a dataframe and I converted it into a new csv file but when I read this new csv file I get a ' Unamed: 0 ' column which has row index's. I need to avoid this column. I even tried to delete the this column and save this dataframe into new csv file but still after that I get the same Unamed: 0 column in next new csv file as well.

I even tried to delete this column and save this dataframe into new csv file. When I droped that column it got droped in the code but when I saved this dataframe as a new csv file I get the same Unamed: 0 column in next new csv file as well.

Answer (score 0):

When writing to csv, use `index=False` to avoid including the index.

```py
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

When reading the csv file, you can use `index_col` to specify the column to use as an index:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=0)  # Use 1st column as index
```

You can also use `usecols` to specify the columns to read:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=[cols_to_include])
```

See [pandas I/O](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files) for more info.